# VueJS: Can I declare dynamically in computed:?

Tags: vue.js

From this piece of code:

```
<ul id="messages-list">
    <li v-for="message in messages"><input v-model="messageXX"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I have `message01`, `message02`... declared in computed values ?

Comment: You cannot use computed in v-model since you cannot write to computed - which v-model does.

Comment: That is not true. If you declare a set and get methode for the computed property v-model works fine.

Comment: How do you expect to reference `message01`, etc.? `messageXX` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable but not elegant.

Basically, generate an object dynamically and merge it into `computed`.

Here's a simple example.

```
let dynamicComputed = {};
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  dynamicComputed[`message` + i] = {
    get() {
      // get operation
    },
    set() {
      // set operation
    }
  };
}

export default {
  computed: {
    exampleComputed() {
      return "example Computed values";
    },
    ...dynamicComputed
  }
};
```